# just_audio - Audio player after completer, start from the beginning

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, slider, just-audio

I created player audio and I used the [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) plugin, I have a problem when the audio player completes and does not return to the beginning. I tried to use `player.playerStateStream.listen()` but when I click on the play icon it does not play the audio and the start duration does not change to 0, but when I manually move the slider it works, how can this problem be solved?

[image]

**Edit:**

What am I need?

I need after audio complete the slider back to the beginning and reset duration just like the first time I played the audio and pause the audio with `onPressed` play audio.

**Code:**

```
String currentTime = "", endTime = "";
double minDuration = 0, maxDuration = 0, currentDuration = 0;

void setAudio(String url) async {
    setState(() => isLoadAudio = true);
    await player.setUrl(url);
    currentDuration = minDuration;
    maxDuration = player.duration!.inMilliseconds.toDouble();
    setState(() {
      currentTime = getDuration(currentDuration);
      endTime = getDuration(maxDuration);
    });
    isPlaying = false;
    changeStatusPlaying();
    player.positionStream.listen((duration) {
      currentDuration = duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble();
      setState(() => currentTime = getDuration(currentDuration));
    });
    setState(() => isLoadAudio = false);
    player.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
      if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
        setState(() {
          currentDuration = minDuration;
          if (isRepeating == true) {
            isPlaying = true;
          } else {
            isPlaying = false;
            isRepeating = false;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
void changeStatusPlaying() {
    setState(() => isPlaying = !isPlaying);
    isPlaying ? player.play() : player.pause();
    currentDuration == maxDuration ? isPlaying : !isPlaying;
  }

String getDuration(double value) {
    Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: value.round());
    return [duration.inHours, duration.inMinutes, duration.inSeconds]
        .map((e) => e.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, "0"))
        .join(":");
  }

Slider(
   value: currentDuration,
   min: minDuration,
   max: maxDuration,
   onChanged: (v) {
     currentDuration = v;
     playAudio(currentDuration);
   },
),
```

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing the same problem. After playing once, when the processing state becomes completed, I can't play it again

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this:
        
bool _isPlaying = false;
bool _isCompleted = false;
Duration? _duration = Duration.zero;
Duration? _position = Duration.zero; 
                
After player has completed, move position to Duration(seconds: 0)   
                        
            Init state  
                            
                            @override
                              void initState() {
                                _initLoadFile();
                                // Listen player states
                                _audioPlayer.playerStateStream.listen((event) async {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _isPlaying = event.playing;
                                  });
                                  if (event.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _isPlaying = false;
                                      _position = const Duration(seconds: 0);
                                      _isCompleted = true;
                                    });
                                  }
                                });
                                // Listen audio duration
                                _audioPlayer.durationStream.listen((newDuration) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _duration = newDuration;
                                  });
                                });
                                // Listen audio position
                                _audioPlayer.positionStream.listen((newPosition) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _position = newPosition;
                                  });
                                });
                                super.initState();
                              }
                            
                            
                    In widget
                            
                    ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    if (!_isPlaying) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _isPlaying = true;
                                        _isCompleted = false;
                                      });
                                      await _audioPlayer.play();
                                      if (_isCompleted) {
                                        await _audioPlayer.seek(const Duration(seconds: 0));
                                        await _audioPlayer.pause();
                                      }
                                    }
                                    if (_isPlaying) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _isPlaying = false;
                                      });
                                      await _audioPlayer.pause();
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(
                                    _isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the audio player to loop:

```
player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);
```

Full example (put your audio file at /assets/audio):

```
class MySimplePlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name, asset;

  const MySimplePlayer(this.name, String filename)
      : this.asset = "assets/audio/$filename";

  @override
  _MySimplePlayerState createState() => _MySimplePlayerState();
}

class _MySimplePlayerState extends State<MySimplePlayer> {
  late AudioPlayer player;
  bool _ready = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    player = AudioPlayer();
    player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.one);    
    player.setAsset(widget.asset).then((_) {
      if (mounted) setState(() => _ready = true);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    player.stop();
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!_ready) return const SizedBox();

    return Card(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(width: 16),
          Expanded(child: Text(widget.name)),
          if (!player.playing)
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
              onPressed: () async {
                player.play();
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          if (player.playing)
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
              onPressed: () async {
                await player.pause();
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
            onPressed: () async {
              await player.stop();
              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 16),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, could you explain more?

Comment: @developer1996 What do you mean? You want it to loop, just set it to loop and it will loop... loop means "play the same song again and again" in this context.

Comment: I mean when the song complete the slider back to start position and duration 0 and with pause button

Comment: @developer1996 It will automatically go back to the beginning, just try it out... and to pause, call `player.pause()`. I will give you a full example to try.

Comment: sorry, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by pausing the audio once the processingState is completed, then player.seek(Duration.zero);

```
StreamBuilder<PlayerState>(
      stream: player.playerStateStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (snapshot.data?.processingState ==
             ProcessingState.completed) {
             player.pause();
              player.seek(Duration.zero);
            }

             return Icon(
                snapshot.data?.playing == true
                    ? Icons.pause
                    : Icons.play_arrow,
        );
   }),
```